# Unable to update specific entries in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where some entries in `column_1` have `NaN` values. I want to replace these by the corresponding values in `column_2`. Both columns hold `float64` values.

I tried the following but strangely it does not update the values.

```
  ix = np.isnan(mydf.loc[:,'column_1'])
  mydf[ix]['column_1'] = tchart[ix]['column_2']
```

Really strange, since I can perfectly see that:

```
mydf[ix]['column_1']
```

is the series with the NaN values

and that

```
mydf[ix]['column_2']
```

has valid values.

Why isn't it working?

I can't even do:

```
mydf[ix]['column_1'] = 45
```

Comment: you are modifying a copy, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), use ``mydf.loc[ix,'columns_1'] = value``

Comment: Thanks @Jeff that fixed it. I have been working with Pandas for a few months now, and this completely caught me by surprise. I you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of chained indexing. For getting values, this is generally ok; however for setting values, it **may** or **may not** work as you may be trying to set values on a copy. It is always better to set via the indexers `ix/loc` for multi-dimensional setting.

In this example, use `mydf.loc[ix,'columns_1'] = 45`

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) for a more complete explanation.