# IPython + pandas oneliner not working

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, dataframe

I am trying to do a oneliner on IPython but I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. The code is the following:

```
 for zzz in ddd.index: zzz1 = zzz.split('///'); zzz3 = [zzz2.strip() for zzz2 in zzz1 if len(zzz1) > 1]; for zzz4 in zzz3: ddd.ix[zzz4]['Class'] = ddd.ix[zzz]['Class']; del ddd.ix[zzz]
```

I can explain it as:
For each value on the index of DataFrame `ddd` I split it using `///` as a separator. Then, if there are multiple values returned, I create a row for each value and remove the original row.
In example I have:

```
             Class
lal          1
eri /// iii  2
aks          3
```

I want to obtain

```
             Class
lal          1
eri          2
iii          2
aks          3
```

The first column (`lal', 'eri', ... ) is the index of dataframe.

How can I achieve this? I have searched through the documentation but I did not manage out how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552248/unable-to-update-specific-entries-in-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment29014515_19552248, use ``ddd.ix[zzz4,'Class`] = ddd.ix[zzz,'Class']``

Comment: It doesn't work.. maybe it does not allow two for on one line with this syntax?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why the interest in putting this one line?  Do you have some sort of anti-vertical prejudice?  That's going to be a problem in Python, because writing good code involves `if/elif/else` and `try/except`, and you can't put those on one line.

Comment: Lol, my bad. So do I, I was just playing with IPython to create a pipeline incrementally just to see how to do something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version at the opposite end of the spectrum from @Jeff's: horribly *slow*, but pretty clear, I think.

```
index_pairs = [(ind, subind.strip()) for ind in df.index for subind in ind.split("///")]
old_i, new_i = zip(*index_pairs)
df2 = df.ix[list(old_i)]
df2.index = new_i
```

Note that **this assumes the original indices are unique**.

---

Start with our frame:

```
>>> df
             Class
lal              1
eri /// iii      2
aks              3
```

Make a list of pairs connecting the original index with as many new subindices as needed:

```
>>> index_pairs = [(ind, subind.strip()) for ind in df.index for subind in ind.split("///")]
>>> index_pairs
[('lal', 'lal'), ('eri /// iii', 'eri'), ('eri /// iii', 'iii'), ('aks', 'aks')]
```

Transpose:

```
>>> old_i, new_i = zip(*index_pairs)
>>> old_i
('lal', 'eri /// iii', 'eri /// iii', 'aks')
>>> new_i
('lal', 'eri', 'iii', 'aks')
```

Use the old indices to index into `df`:

```
>>> df2 = df.ix[list(old_i)]
>>> df2
             Class
lal              1
eri /// iii      2
eri /// iii      2
aks              3
```

Reset the indices:

```
>>> df2.index = new_i
>>> df2
     Class
lal      1
eri      2
iii      2
aks      3
```

Comment: Assuming dataframe size cannot be too big, this answer reflects better the result I needed and it's not too expensive I think..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do here.

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
             A  B
0          lal  1
1  eri /// iii  2
2          aks  3
```

Here is a horribly long expression to do this. Good news is that this will be pretty fast.

```
In [56]: split = df['A'].str.split('\s+\/\/\/\s+').apply(Series)

In [57]: split
Out[57]: 
     0    1
0  lal  NaN
1  eri  iii
2  aks  NaN

In [58]: indexed = split.unstack().dropna()

In [59]: indexed
Out[59]: 
0  0    lal
   1    eri
   2    aks
1  1    iii
dtype: object

 In [61]: grouped = indexed.groupby(level=1).apply(
           lambda x: Series(x.values,index=list(x.index.get_level_values(1))))

In [62]: grouped
Out[62]: 
0  0    lal
1  1    eri
   1    iii
2  2    aks
dtype: object

In [63]: grouped.reset_index().set_index('level_1')
Out[63]: 
         level_0    0
level_1              
0              0  lal
1              1  eri
1              1  iii
2              2  aks
```

Comment: I think the OP is after `pd.DataFrame({"Index": ["lal", "eri", "iii", "aks"], "Class": [1,2,2,3]})`, although I don't know if `Index` is meant to be a column or an index.

Comment: @DSM you are right, and `Index` is the index.. I'll update the question